# Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to install `mysqlclient` by runing `pip install mysqlclient` on my shell, and it says the following error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.0.3.tar.gz (88 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'g:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_7zysw22'
       cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\
  Complete output (23 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'g:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Userython\Include\mysqlclient'
         cwd: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\MySQLdb\constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'g:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-rhaf8m0z\\mysqlclient_21d1d7a0b8c4431382bfeeefc437906d\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-l20p5rko\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed 
--compile --install-headers 'g:\python\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am using python version `3.8.3` and no `mysql` software is installed on my pc, just `xampp` is installed.

**Please suggest, how can I fix it?**

Comment: Read the error: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"

Comment: I just install it with your given link. but the error still arise.